# Inherit from const-ized class (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants

Say I have a class called DataStructure and another class called ConstDataStructure related as below:

```
class DataStructure
{
    public:
        DataStructure();
        virtual ~DataStructure();
        unsigned char * data();

        template <class T>
        void setData(T data);

    private:
        unsigned char * data_;
}
```

and

```
class ConstDataStructure
{
    public:
        ConstDataStructure();
        virtual ~ConstDataStructure();
        const unsigned char * data() const;

    private:
        const unsigned char * data_;
}
```

I am asked to "make DataStructure inherit from ConstDataStructure for reuse". However, this doesn't seem to be a logical statement. I've been taught that inheritance is like an "is-a" relationship, so if A inherits from B, that's like saying that "A is a B". Here, it would be like saying that "DataStructure is a ConstDataStructure", which doesn't seem to be the case, as the DataStructure class has mutable data_ object with a setter function, while the ConstDataStructure necessarily has neither. It seems more natural for ConstDataStructure to inherit from DataStructure, since it is the same kind of class, but a more specific instance of it. Or, to simply not inherit in either direction, though that does seem redundant.

Am I wrong here? Is the request sensical? If so, how does inheriting from a const-ized version of the class work?

Comment: You are right that inheritance shouldn't be abused just for code reuse. However, this should probably just be `DataStructure` and `const DataStructure`. There's no reason I can think of for why you'd want to have these separate

Comment: "A is a B" means that you can do to an A ecerything you can do to a B, and maybe more. It then makes sense that a const data structure, having only read access, is the base class of the normal data structure that *also* has write access.

Comment: Is there any difference between a const class and a class with const members?

Comment: @Quentin I see how this could be the case, but would that not mean that DataStructure inherits the constness of data() and data_?

Comment: Warning: You appear to be violating the Rule Of Three.

Comment: There is something similar already used in the standard library:  the relationship between a `const_iterator` and an `iterator`.

Comment: `ConstDataStructure` doesn't appear to have any means to initialize its `data_` member. It's not clear what purpose it serves.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that is handled in the constructor. Here the default constructor doesn't take in any arguments, but you could imagine one that does would be written similarly. I don't think it's necessary to write each possible type of constructor explicitly to ask this question.

Comment: If you could modify `ConstDataStructure` to have its `data_` member `protected` and non-const, then `DataStructure` could derive from it and drop its own `data_` member. Alternatively (and perhaps preferably), create a common base class that houses the data, and derive both `DataStructure` and `ConstDataStructure` from that.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 `data()` can be overloaded to have a `const` and a non-`const` version. As for `data_`, it is an implementation detail -- and the demonstration that a sensible interface does not necessarily map to a straightforward implementation :)